# How do I use a runtime factory object for a semiring implementation in Scala?

Tags: scala, type-conversion, factory

I am attempting to model algebraic semirings in Scala. I'm running into type conversion problems that make it appear that it is not possible to do what I want to do in Scala. I'm hoping someone can direct me to the aspect of Scala's typing system that I have misunderstood.

(Please bear with the long setup for this question. I've pared it down as much as I can.)

A semiring is a set of items over which is defined binary addition (+) and multiplication (*) operators and their identity elements, called zero and one, respectively. For example the Integer Semiring is defined over the integers where + and * are the standard operations from arithmetic and zero and one are the integers 0 and 1. A more exotic example is the Boolean Semiring, which is defined over the values True and False, where + is logical OR, * is logical AND, zero is False, and one is True.

To model this I define a trait that specifies the appropriate binary operators.

```
trait SemiringElement {
  /**
   * The element type
   */
  type E
  /**
   * The type returned by the the addition and multiplication operators
   */
  type R <: SemiringElement
  val value: E

  def +(that: R): R

  def *(that: R): R

  override def toString = value.toString
}
```

Case classes instantiate elements of particular semirings. For example, the Boolean Semiring would look like this.

```
case class BooleanSemiringElement(init: Boolean) extends SemiringElement {
  type E = Boolean
  type R = BooleanSemiringElement
  val value = init

  def +(that: BooleanSemiringElement#R) = BooleanSemiringElement(value || that.value)

  def *(that: BooleanSemiringElement#R) = BooleanSemiringElement(value && that.value)
}
```

I additionally have a Semiring trait which specifies zero and one elements.

```
trait Semiring {
  type E <: SemiringElement
  /**
   * The addition identity
   */
  val zero: E
  /**
   * The multiplication identity
   */
  val one: E
}
```

Specific semiring objects return zero and one elements of the appropriate type.

```
object BooleanSemiring extends Semiring {
  type E = BooleanSemiringElement

  val zero = BooleanSemiringElement(false)
  val one = BooleanSemiringElement(true)
}
```

The Semiring objects are essentially factory singletons that know how to return identity elements of the appropriate type.

I want to be able to write algorithms that work with semiring elements in general. I use the Semiring factory objects in order to be able to specify a particular semiring at runtime rather than compile time. For example, say I have an object that maintains a map between strings and semiring elements.

```
class ElementMap(s: Semiring) {
  val m = mutable.Map[String, SemiringElement]()
}
```

If I instantiate this with a call like so:

```
val x = new ElementMap(BooleanSemiring)
```

I would like x.m to be a String->BooleanSemiringElement map. The problem is what I have is actually a String->SemiringElement map.

```
scala> val x = new ElementMap(BooleanSemiring)
x: ElementMap = ElementMap@46cf97b
scala> x.m
res2: scala.collection.mutable.Map[String,SemiringElement] = Map()
scala> x.m("one") = BooleanSemiring.one
scala> x.m("one") + BooleanSemiring.one
<console>:12: error: type mismatch;
 found   : BooleanSemiring.one.type (with underlying type BooleanSemiring.BooleanSemiringElement)
 required: _1.R where val _1: SemiringElement
              x.m("one") + BooleanSemiring.one
                                       ^
```

If I was willing to specify the type at compile time rather than runtime I could make the element type a generic like so:

```
class ElementMap[BooleanSemiring]...
```

but then I'd need a factory method to create all the different kinds of ElementMap objects. Putting the factory smarts inside a Semiring trait makes more sense architecturally. What I want to be able to say is something like this:

```
class ElementMap(s: Semiring) {
  val m = mutable.Map[String, s.E]()
}
```

that is: create a map from strings to the element type E returned by the Semiring object supplied to the constructor. I can't figure out how to do this. I've tried various syntactic tricks and implicit conversions to no avail.

Is there a way write an ElementMap that is configured with a Semiring constructor parameter at runtime, or am I taking the wrong approach? I'm new to Scala and trying to do things in a Scala-esque manner. I feel like I've painted myself into a corner here, but I'm not sure exactly where the misstep lies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried capturing the specific type of `s` as a type parameter?

```
scala> class ElementMap[S <: Semiring](s: S) {
     |   val m = collection.mutable.Map[String, S#E]()
     | }
defined class ElementMap

scala> val x = new ElementMap(BooleanSemiring)
x: ElementMap[BooleanSemiring.type] = ElementMap@6544c984

scala> x.m("one") = BooleanSemiring.one

scala> x.m("one") + BooleanSemiring.one
res0: BooleanSemiringElement = true
```

You could do something similar with the element type:

```
scala> class ElementMap[SE <: SemiringElement](s: Semiring { type E = SE }) {
     |   val m = collection.mutable.Map[String, SE]()
     | }
defined class ElementMap

scala> val x = new ElementMap(BooleanSemiring)
x: ElementMap[BooleanSemiringElement] = ElementMap@4cf353e5

scala> x.m("one") = BooleanSemiring.one

scala> x.m("one") + BooleanSemiring.one
res1: BooleanSemiringElement = true
```

The problem with your version is that you're throwing away all of the type information about `s`—from the perspective of `ElementMap`, it's just a `Semiring`.

(As a side note, ad-hoc polymorphism via type classes is probably a more natural way to solve this problem in Scala. See for example the way [Scalaz 7](http://code.google.com/p/scalaz/) represents similar algebraic structures.)

Comment: Thanks. Ad-hoc polymorphism does seem like it's intended for this kind of situation. I'm reading up on it now. Is there a specific example in Scalaz that comes close to this problem?

Comment: `Monoid` is probably the closest.